# When is a SQLite database initially created in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am familiar with the notion of the SQLiteOpenHelper class and its onCreate & onUpgrade method, but *when* is the database itself actually instantiated for the first time? Is it during installation of the app, or upon the first call of getWritableDatabase()/getReadableDatabase() ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Database, as file on disk, is created when you call `getWritableDatabase` or `getReadableDatabase`.

Just read the docs of [SQLiteOpenHelper constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#SQLiteOpenHelper(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory,%20int)) ;-)

Answer (score 4):

> Is it during installation of the app

No.

> upon the first call of getWritableDatabase()/getReadableDatabase() ?

Yes. This is why it is important to call those methods on a background thread, as how long they take depends upon whether or not the database needs to be created or upgraded.